# Count how many gifts of each type were sent

Tags: postgresql

I have a gifts table

```
id | name | price
```

and a giftings table to record everything that is sent

```
id | gift | from | to
```

with giftings.gift being a FK to gifts.id and from and to being FK to a users table

I want to count how many of each gift a user has received, so an output would be like this

```
star: 5
diamond: 20
heart: 0
```

At the moment, I think its working with this query but It wont show a gift if the count is 0.

```
select gifts.id, gifts.name, count(giftings.gift) from gifts join giftings on gifts.id = giftings.gift where "to" = 5839 group by gifts.id, gifts.name
```

I have tried different joins, and I know I could do this with a sub query but im trying to do it in a single query because I know its possible.

Many thanks

Comment: Use a left join instead.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: @Deniz a left join will not work in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `LEFT` join and the condition for the user in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT g.id, g.name, 
       COUNT(s.gift) 
FROM gifts g LEFT JOIN giftings s  
ON g.id = s.gift AND s."to" = 5839 
GROUP BY g.id, g.name;
```

Comment: works perfect, thanks :D